# SEDE query to find how many questions remain unanswered related to a particular tag

Tags: support, questions, data-explorer, data-dump

For example, there are N questions which have a tag named X (there might be other tags also) and M of the questions remain unanswered. I require the number M associated with all tags in Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are [thousands of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) on Stack Overflow. You need the number M for all of them? Is this for some data analysis stuff?

Comment: @Blue Yes, I need the number for all of them. It is for an empirical study purpose.

Comment: @SaikatMondal You'll need to clarify the question a bit more. Say, do you need the "live" values, or will 1-week-out-of-date values also suffice?

Comment: @Blue live value is preferable but values of 1-week-out-of-date are also okay. Basically, I am asking the SEDE query. I tried but it exceeds the time limit with no records.

Comment: @Blue I also tried top N, but did not find get the result. So, I thought that my query might not efficient (or wrong). Could you please try for me once?

Comment: This will count all questions with no answers for a given tag https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/1053037/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh when I give java as Tag name it returns 0. Moreover, it is not feasible to provide such a high number of tags one by one.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Top voted unanswered question and the associated tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1053063). That is a start, perhaps someone more skilled in SQL will improve that for you. As is it sorts the highest voted unanswered questions and shows all the tags for each question. You *could* change it to sort on single tags but then there would be duplicate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1053083/tags-by-of-unanswered-count) you go:

[image]

```
SELECT t.TagName, COUNT(DISTINCT(p.Id))
  FROM Tags AS t
  INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt ON t.Id = pt.TagId
  INNER JOIN Posts AS p ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  WHERE p.AnswerCount = 0
  GROUP BY t.TagName
  ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT(p.Id)) DESC
```

Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1053083) the query to experiment. You might be interested in the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) as well.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh answers don't appear in the `PostTags` table, so filtering on post type isn't necessary.

Comment: it’s always run faster for me when I added that information to the join

Comment: I've done some testing, and for me it depends on which version of the query I try first, that's always the slowest one.